# PycahrmでAnacondaが「アクティブ」状態になりません！

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, powershell, pycharm

Windowsで環境変数設定後にPycharmでターミナルを開いたのですが、画面キャプチャのようにAnacondaが読み込まれていないようです。Anaconda promptにて「conda init powershell」を実行したみても改善することができませんでした！[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 環境変数の設定前に起動したPycharmを終了し、改めてPycharmを起動してみてください。

Comment: @akira ejiri コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り再起動後にターミナルでpythonを呼び出すとAnacondaを読み込むことができました！

Comment: 解決してよかったです。コメントを回答として投稿しました。よろしければ回答の承認をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

環境変数は親プロセスから子プロセスに引き継がれます。
環境変数の設定前に起動したPycharmを終了し、改めてPycharmを起動すると設定済の環境変数が引き継がれ、PycharmやPycharmのターミナルで環境変数が有効になります。

Comment: 回答の承認「✓」を行いました！初めて利用しましたので、もし承認されてないようでしたら再度ご連絡頂けると幸いです！